# Passing through a params array to another method

Tags: c#, arrays, parameters

I've ended up with two procedures, with very similar arguments and identical functionality, whose arguments are as follows:

```
   private string BuildResponse(string value1, string value2, params string[] parameters)
   private string BuildResponse(MyObject values, params string[] parameters)
```

In this case, `MyObject` has two properties; `value1` and `value2`. I was initially trying to implement the second as follows:

```
   private string BuildResponse(MyObject values, params string[] parameters) {
       return BuildResponse (values.value1, values.value2, parameters);
   }
```

Unfortunately, the compiler threw a warning relating to the `best overloaded method match for ...` - i.e. I couldn't simply pass `parameters` (which is a `string[]`) through like this.

So - how can I pass a `string[]` into a method whose signature ends with a `params` variable?

*(I'm now replacing the `params string[]` with another collection type instead hence the past tense, but it would be interesting to know whether what I was trying to do was even possible. If it isn't, feel free to state "no" and provide references)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should have worked. The problem most likely was that `value1` or `value2` wasn't of type `string`. The `params` array was not the problem.

Comment: You're close, I was being a bit daft - when I created my simplified version I managed to accidentally **not** make a mistake that was in the live code.